# How to fix SELECT statement and cookie counting in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, select

I'm trying to put data in a repeater and this works. Only I want an extra column with the amount of the id is in that cookie that is just read by the loop.

The text wil be put in a label somthing like this:
 `<asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval( aantal ) %>' />`

I tried like the follow things:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Naam, Prijs, GerechtId from [1A-Gerecht] WHERE GerechtId =('" + art + "') AND aantal = ('" + aantal + "')";


cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Naam, Prijs, GerechtId from [1A-Gerecht] WHERE GerechtId =('" + art + "')";
cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText + aantal;
```

The whole look likes the follow:

```
foreach(string art in mandje.Values.AllKeys)
{
    int aantal = int.Parse(mandje[art]);
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Hi"].ConnectionString);

    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Naam, Prijs, GerechtId from [1A-Gerecht] WHERE GerechtId =('" + art + "')";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    d2.DataSource = dt;
    d2.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use parameterized queries.

Comment: There are other issues too like instantiating objects inside the loop, thus creating them over and over. But let's see if we can fix his current issue. But you are right, inline SQL which he has is not recommended but it depends if he is getting the injecting value form a query string or an input box.